# Rubymine syntax highlighting in js.erb files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-highlighting, rubymine

I have javascript files that have embedded ruby. While functionally everything works fine, the syntax highlighting as well as the error inspection function of RubyMine 2016 has issues with that.

The first time i embed ruby in the javascript file by using the `<%= ... %>` syntax, something goes horribly wrong. See attached screenshot. I guess that RubyMine interprets the `<` sign as a comparison operator.

As i assume that embedding ruby in JavaScript is quite common, is there a way to make RubyMine play nice with my functional (and correct) code?

Otherwise it looks like i have a huge number of errors, and editing becomes quite unintuitive:

[image: over 9000 errors]

Comment: What is the filename?

Comment: Are you using the Atom editor?

Comment: SergioTulentsev: the filename is something.js.erb
HarlemSquirrel: no, i am using RubyMine 2016.1.1

Comment: Hm, yes, you're right, without .erb extension it wouldn't work. However, my installation of rubymine doesn't have any problems in the small snippet I tried. Post the full content of the file.